# I want to restrict users to copy files from Hyper-V VM, How should i achieve it?

Tags: virtual-machine, file-sharing, hyper-v

As i am newbie in virutalization. My boss gave me a task. He want to share some files with all finance employees but do not want them to copy, delete or edit those files, only users can see them. I tried to find a answer in google but it seems google is not going to help me or i am searching for wrong thing.

May anyone here who help me to achieve that. All he want me to create a VM for that and share those files from that VM.

I am using Server 2012 R2. A win 7 Virtual Machine.

Thanks,
Arvind Chouhan

Comment: I presume that by "see a file", you mean "view a file", not "see a file listed in a folder". Then, obviously, if one can view a file, one must have read access rights. Once one has opened the file, one can save it elsewhere, where one has write permissions, including USB media. Hopefully, even your boss will be able to apply this amount of common sense to the scenario. The best protection you can get is to isolate the data and the application on a server and only _display_ the application on the client (Citrix, X). Still, care must be taken, and screenshots will work.

Comment: ok. Understand it. But can i apply a group policy to disable copy paste for that data? If yes, How to get that?

Comment: There is no one secure way to prevent this. If it was the movies industries would long since have applied it to their products. You can make things harder to copy for the end user, but as long as it gets shown on the screen they will be able to copy it.

Comment: How can you share a file but not allow the person to have a copy that doesn't make sense. The very most you have say .PDF where it doesn't allow you to (save, print to file, print that sort of thing) but if you have access to the file you can copy the file.  There is no group policy for the type of permissions you want, I would go as far and say, you cannot share a file without creating a copy of the file.  Your boss has given you an impossible task.

Comment: @Ramhound i will give access to vm to the users with an AD user account. Tell me what is possible from below point. I found it an alternative: 1. Disable right click. 2. Hide all desktop icons. 3. hide start menu items (using registry if possible). 4. Hide notification icons. 5. No access to browsers. 5. only xls/.ppt etc pasted on desktop will be accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some how i achieved my question's answer by using group policy editor. I removed everything from desktop, block network sharing and use of control panel. but it take some more manual work to do when copying data on that Vm's desktop. Everytime i need to turn on Network Sharing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need RMS for this. Not a very easy and simple thing...... That's the only thing that can prevent screenshots and copying of an open file that you do have Read access to.